# I can not make a view clickable

Tags: android, onclick

I just have an simple xml layout  like this

```
    <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="#404040" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:onClick="clickBack"
                    android:src="@drawable/btn_arrow_back" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_back"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:background="#404040"
                    android:onClick="clickBack2"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And then I set

```
public void clickBack(View v) {
        finish();
    }

public void clickBack2(View v){
        finish();
    }
```

The problem is I just can click the ImageView but I can not click the TextView. Please tell me what wrong with this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well 20dp is too short the official guideline by google to view to be touchable is 48dp try increasing the size of ImageView

Comment: Try TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_back) ; text.setOnClickListener.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to diagnose this problem

Answer (score 0):

Thank L-X for your information, but I don't want to change the dp of ImageView so I wrap those two with another relative layout and problem is solved ;)

```
 <RelativeLayout 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:onClick="clickBack">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"

                    android:src="@drawable/btn_arrow_back" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_back"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:background="#404040"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```